# Why mySql returns only the first word of a string?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `galleryCategory`";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                  echo "<div title = {$row['category_title']}>";
                  echo "</div><br />";
        }
```

The output should be (for example) "**bmw 3 series**".
**What this really shown me just a word "bmw"**

What is needed to get the full string?
thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing quotes for title attribute

```
echo '<div title = "'.$row['category_title'].'">';
echo '</div><br />';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't MySQL but the way you define the attribute in HTML.

Replace

```
echo "<div title = {$row['category_title']}>";
```

with

```
echo "<div title=\"{$row['category_title']}\">";
```

or (more readable)

```
echo '<div title="'.$row['category_title'].'">';
```

Comment: or `echo '<div title="'.$row['category_title'].'">';`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes... I was editing to look for the easiest to read version.

Comment: Third alternative is the only feasible one since you also need to call `htmlspecialchars()`.